# How to convert a number to double data type in javascript/ typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have one input filed where the user can enter any numbers 
eg: 12  12.1  12.30 12.34
I have to pass this value in a service call here i can only send the value as **number but with 2 decimal points**

```
let a = input //a will be a type of number
let b = a.toFixed(2) //b will be type of string
let c = Number(b) //it will automatically cut unwanted '0'
console.log(c);
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
//input is 12
a=12
b="12.00"
c=12

//input is 12.30
a=12.30
b="12.30"
c=12.3
```

*I want a method, using which i can input a value as a number and output will be number with 2 decimal points.*

Comment: All numeric types in typescript are `number` which are floating point values, so I don't think data type conversion is what you're after here.  Seems like you just want to take any number and round/truncate it or right-pad w/ zeroes to two digits.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: You can try getting the value of your input, `parseFloat` it and then `toFixed` it

Comment: "Double" does not mean two decimal places, it means double precision. There is no way to specify a number to a fixed number of places except to store it as a string using `.toFixed`. That's the whole reason that method returns a string in the first place.

Comment: Actually, you may want to use [toExponential](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp) method, so you can store your `12.30` number as `1230e-2` and don't loose that zero.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a number to always display in two decimal places, you can do as below. It will round all the numbers to two decimal places(including doubles).

```
function twoDecimal(yourNumber){
    return parseFloat(Math.round(yourNumber * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}

let x=twoDecimal(10);
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/17f167b50ba7c719ec3f2616e045cf1a

go through the above screenshot
I had input the value as number :12
after this (Math.round(yourNumber * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) value changed to= "12.00"
but after parseFolat() the value changed to 12
My objective is if i gave 12(type number) i want to get output/return as 12.00(type of number).